# Уведомления в браузере ( типа вк или другое)

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Делаю новостной сайт . При добавлении новости осуществляется уведомление всем пользователям о новой новости . Реализовал серверную часть с помощью Rachet и ZMQ , с клиентской частью не совсем понимаю как сделать . Пока что сделал уведомления только через консоль , все работает . Но не через консоль же пользователей оповещать . Вопрос в том , как сделать оповещения что-то типа вк ? какие инструменты использовать , чтобы большинством браузеров поддерживалось? Спасибо за ответы

Comment: вы про нотификацию? есть полно плагинов  https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=jquery+notification  например https://notifyjs.com/ или http://ned.im/noty/#/about и прочие.. просто надо поискать в стиле `jquery notification`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть два типа пуш уведомлений: на одном вебсокеты точеные, с другим проблем тоже хватает.

**Первый тип** - это если у вас вкладка с сайтом открыта, соответственно ваш js там преспокойно выполняется.
**Второй тип** - настоящие пуш уведомления. Если у вас вкладка с сайтом не выделена или вообще закрыта. Но браузер открыт при этом.

**Для реализации первого типа** вам по сути нужна любая обычная система мессаджей от вашего сервера вашему клиенту. Это могут быть хоть вебсокеты, может быть лонг поллинг, может быть sse. Да хоть сигнальные костры на гуглмапс =)
Алексей Шиманский в своем комментарии подразумевал именно этот тип сообщений.

**Со вторым типом все сложнее.** И реализовать их "просто прикрутив какую-то библиотеку или плагин на js" нельзя. Потому что нету этого вашего клиентского js когда вкладка закрыта. Ну собственно почему у клиента должен выполняться ваш скрипт если он не у вас на сайте?

Сделать это можно, но на пути нас поджидают неприятности.

Начнем с того, что есть спецификация [**Notifications api**](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/). Но разумеется она еще совсем не готова, браузеры ее нормально не поддерживают (что поддерживать то, что десять раз еще поменяется). Использовать в кровавом энтерпрайзе нельзя точно. Если у вас много энтузиазма и смузи, можете попробовать прикрутить для каких-то браузеров.

И поэтому решается это сейчас так: крупные вендоры браузеров предоставляют свои сервисы, через которые можно соответственно можно работать с браузерами этих вендоров. [**GCM**](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) и [**APNS**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) о которых упомянул в своем ответе misc - это соответственно такие сервисы для гугла и эпла. Есть пачка и от менее крупных компаний.

Это разумеется порождает следующую проблему: для того чтобы у вас все было чудесно кроссбраузерно и розовые единороги прыгали по зеленой лужайке, вам нужно найти как можно больше таких сервисов и для каждого написать прослойку на своей стороне, которая будет этот сервис дергать. А универсального формата нету. А сервисов не так уж и мало. И каждый что-то да меняет иногда, и придется поддерживать как-то этот зоопарк.

Соответственно появились прослойки разной степени надежности, функциональности и платности. Упомянутые пользователем mics [onesignal.com](http://onesignal.com) и [clevertap.com](https://clevertap.com/) относятся к таким прослойкам.

А теперь к плохому. Готовое работающее исключительно бесплатное решение я не нашел (искал где-то полдня, если кто-то подскажет, буду благодарен.). Есть решения платные, есть сервисы предоставляющие бесплатную триалку и есть "бесплатные".

Вот onesignal.com - это сервис "бесплатный". Денег за свое решение они с вас не возьмут, но, насколько я понял из их соглашения, оставляют за собой право использовать и продавать данные которые вы через них пересылаете, третьим лицам. Вам подходит? Тогда попробуйте их.

Comment: спасибо за ответ . мне нужно реализовать именно первый тип

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял, вы для отправки Web Push (если это все-таки они, по вашему вопросу не совсем понятно) зачем-то используете вебсокеты. Для этого используют, например, чистые GCM/APNS, или сервисы, которые нюансы подключения к GCM/APNS решают за вас, например:

1. https://onesignal.com/
2. https://clevertap.com/

Comment: я так понимаю , GCM/APNS используюттся для отправки уведомлений на моб.телефоны , да ?

Comment: @KolyaVantukh может и на телефоны, а может и в браузер

Comment: не знал ,спасибо. но в чем же веб-сокеты плохи?

Comment: @KolyaVantukh они хорошие. Но в браузер вы уведомление через них не отправите.

Comment: но можно же какие-то библиотеки или плагины на js использовать  с помощью которых это реально сделать?

Comment: @KolyaVantukh к сожалению, насколько я знаю, так сделать нельзя. Вы можете отсылать таким образом нотификации только тем, кто открыл ваш сайт и в вкладке браузера и на момент отправки нотификации находится на нем. Как только пользователь вкладку закрывает - вебсокеты уже не помогут. Только GCM/APNS.

Answer (score 2):

**Minishlink** создал пакет https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php для легкого внедрения пуш нотификаций на бекенде на PHP, также он создал демо на основе этого пакета, его джаваскрипт легко заимствовать в свой проект https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push-php-example.

Answer (score 0):

**Daria Motorina** да Minishlink создал пакет, но PHP версия к сожалению не работает: там используется команда use которая требует установки Composer (композитор, хотя если корректно: нарисован дирижер, то есть программа должна называться Director).

Так вот: это неподходит, так как сторонний плагин скорее всего разопрёт функцию до 100+ кб : посчитайте что будет при одновременных 10-50 вызовах такой функции.

Есть ли у вас либо у того кто будет это читать: полная PHP функция, которая будет работать без сторонних плагинов и будет соответствовать стандартам **FOC** (Full Optimized Code)?

Согласитесь: что 10-20 лет назад, что сейчас принцип **FOC** имеет полное преимущество перед принципом **DRY**.

Для справки:

- **FOC** – Full Optimized Code
- **DRY** – Don't Repeat Yourself

И да: сейчас мы не говорим о том, что NodeJS доступнее только потому, что его продвигает Google (примеров NodeJS действительно больше)
а например принцип DRY продвигает gitHub, сайт, который снова ж таки продвигает и популяризирует Google.

Речь идёт не о монополии (не нужно споров), а вопрос заключается в том: *как этот процес (серверную часть) можно реализовать в PHP по стандартам FOC ?*

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/707087)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).