# Как сделать уведомления о новостях, на которые пользователь подписан?

Tags: push-уведомления, уведомления

Как можно и лучше реализовать нижеописанное?

человек нажимает на кнопку "подписаться на обновления" и, собственно, желательно, чтобы на этом всё кончилось.

Думал использовать уведомления браузера, но так и не понял можно ли реализовать так, чтобы человеку приходили уведомления только о тех новостях, на которые он подписан.

Вариант с отправкой e-mail не рассматриваю.

Comment: Кстати, если вдруг будешь пробовать кучу сервисов, не указанных в ответе — не забудь поделиться списком)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я сам только закончил исследование и могу поделиться.

Первое что стоит упомянуть, если вдруг вы не знали:

> Реализовать их "просто прикрутив какую-то библиотеку или плагин на js" нельзя. 
>   Решается это сейчас так: крупные вендоры браузеров предоставляют свои сервисы, через которые можно соответственно можно работать с браузерами этих вендоров.

Взято из темы  [уведомления в браузере ( типа вк или другое)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/556499/191482). Там же подглядел пару сервисов, которые могут помочь (это конечно же не все сервисы, но для примера хватит):

1. https://onesignal.com/
2. https://clevertap.com/

По примеру *ONESIGNAL* получилось следующее:

Каждому пользователю, который пришел на сайт или кликнув в настройках подписаться на конкретные разделы, можно присвоить любой тег или группу тегов (каждый тег будет соответствовать одному пункту рассылки на сайте). Это можно будет увидеть в соответствующем разделе сервиса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Назначать теги, смотреть идентификатор пользователя, устанавливать различные настройки пользователю можно будет через [Web Push SDK](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/web-push-sdk).

Из изображения выше видно, что у нижнего пользователя теги:

```
{kino:true, delivery:true}
```

То есть абстрактно он подписан на уведомления о кино и доставки. Другой с `{tort:true}` абстрактно подписан на уведомления о разделе "торт".

Теперь воспользовавшись [REST API](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/reference#create-notification),  который предоставляет данный сервис, можно отсылать сообщения, отфильтровывая данные по разным признакам. Если конкретно, то в данном случае мы будем ориентироваться на те теги, которые стоят у пользователя.

Следующий код отошлет сообщение пользователям, подписанным на разделы kino и tort:

```js
function sendMessage($themes){

      $content = array(
          "en" => 'Привет user тут уведомления для юзера, который подписан на '. implode(', ', $themes) .'!'
      );

      $filters = [];
      foreach ($themes as $theme) {
          $themeItem = ["field" => "tag",
              "key" => $theme,
              "relation" => "=",
              "value" => true
          ];
          array_push($filters, $themeItem);
          array_push($filters, ["operator" => "OR"]);
      }

      array_pop($filters);

      $fields = array(
          'app_id' => "a6a6a6a6-6666-6666-6666-a6a6a6a6a6",          
          'filters' => $filters,
          'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
          'contents' => $content
      );

      $fields = json_encode($fields);
      print("\nJSON sent:\n");
      print($fields);


      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'Authorization: Basic SDfojisdofiOIDFJOISjfoisFOIJFDSfjoijOIFJSOIFJoisf'));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);

      return $response;
  }

$themes = ['kino', 'tort'];
$response = sendMessage($themes);
```

---

Соответственно можно в любое время отсылать данные конкретным пользователям.

Всё.

Для данного сервиса есть [подробная документация](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/), поддерживает следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

Happy end! (???)

#### Домашнее задание:

То, что сервисов рассылки Push-уведомлений много - факт. Но я не могу точно сказать какие еще существуют сервисы с **подобным** функционалом. Вам придется просто самому проштудировать сервисы предоставляющие услуги по рассылке и потыкать в настройки и найти что-то подобное.