# Каким образом отправлять разные пуши разным пользователям с помощью OneSignal

Tags: php, curl

В [документации](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification) не совсем ясно указаны лимиты и метод отправки многих разных уведомлений многим разным пользователям.

Можно ли отправляя запрос на создание нотификаций одним массивом создать множество разных нотификаций множеству разных пользователей.

К примеру разослать некоторому количеству пользователей различные сообщения о скидке на различные товары (у каждого пользователя подписка на разные товары).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать уведомления о новостях, на которые пользователь подписан?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657977/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd)

Comment: Маркируешь пользователей тегом по группам, от которого зависит рассылка. Дальше отсылаешь контент соответствующий этому тегу

Comment: Вопрос не хранения или тегирования пользователей, а в том что сообщение у каждого юзера может и должно отличатся. В документации не сказано как отправлять 200 сообщений 200 пользователям, к примеру.

Например по крону в 6 утра отрабатывается задание, в котором формируется массив из кастомизированых сообщений разным пользователям (к примеру тысяче подписаных и протегированных пользователей). Вопрос в том в каком формате этот запрос сформировать для отправки в API.

По одному ли запросу или можно 100 переменных контента по 100 выборкам тега пользователей (при лимите в API 200 за раз).

Comment: Это не БД, а АПИ. В АПИ нельзя отправить 100 разных сообщений одновременно. делай цикл... но что такого ты там рассылаешь, что у тебя **1000** пользователей должны получить разное сообщение?

Comment: Скидочная штука, каждому пользователю интересны разные скидки на разные товары, хотелось бы предупреждать пользователей о количестве товаров со скидкой на которые он подписан. Хотелось бы отправлять уведомление не "На некоторые товары появилась скидка", а более кастомизировано, хотя бы "На 5 товаров в вашем списке появилась скидка". Количество пользователей и скидок жестко проконтролировать нельзя.
Вот хотелось бы понять что за массив отправлять в OS API чтобы оповестить всех пользователей (хотя бы циклами по 100, это уже дело понятное).