# PUSH-уведомления для Android и iOS (Cordova)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, cordova, push

Господа, прошу нас рассудить.

Мы с напарником веб-разработчики (я back, он front). Мы работаем над одним виджетом для CRM, который мы завернули в приложение используя **Cordova** (для кроссплатформености).

Сейчас нам понадобилось прикрутить туда PUSH уведомления.

Перерыв кучу материалов я понял отправку pushей следующим образом:
При установке приложения на телефон пользователь даёт разрешение на отправку push уведомлений, связывается с GCM (FCM) или APNS и мониторит пуши на уровне операционки. (в приложение не обязательно вообще что-то прикручивать). Приложение может быть вообще не запущено.

По версии напарника в приложение нужно добавить запуск дополнительной службы (тестим на Android), что бы уведомления отобразились.

Собственно сабж.
Возможно, что у кого-то из вас появятся ещё идеи по реализации, делитесь.
Всем спасибо.

Comment: Возьмите OneSignal, пройдитесь по документации для Cordova: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk-setup и не будет никаких вопросов

Comment: Вроде никаких доп. служб не нужно. Точнее при клике "Разрешить" уже всё будет запущено и отслеживаться. Останется только стрелять сообщения по документации (во всяком случае так было, когда я пробовал :) )

Comment: Алексей, посоветуйте как можно тестировать пуши без Google Play и AppStore. Вы пробовали на iPhone или Android.

Comment: @VladimirMyagdeev android. а что значит "тестировать пуши без Google Play и AppStore"?  в целом я прикручивал к сайту пуши через onesignal и его документацию https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669285/191482 ...то есть после регистрации в сервисе и указания нужных данных в нём - достаточно потом просто с помощью кода (основанном на доках) отсылать данные и они автоматом приходили подписчикам

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили моё видение)