# yii2 push уведомления, как можно реализовать?

Tags: yii2, уведомления, push

Вопрос заключается в том, как реализовать web push уведомления в yii2. Никак не могу найти наглядную инструкцию.

Суть уведомлений. Добавляется пост который храниться в бд MySQL. При добавлении должно отправляться push уведомления. Есть таблица для хранения токенов. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: github есть готовые, но никак понять их использование.

Comment: А причем тут php фреймворк, это же Service Worker

Comment: Service Worker работает, не могу отправить посты в виде пуш которые находятся в бд.

Comment: @AmirRakhmonov [Как сделать уведомления о новостях, на которые пользователь подписан?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/657977/191482)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский огромное спасибо) но так получилось что я сам нашел эти сервисы, но всё равно благодарю.